# Query performance is really bad with multiple joins and unions, is there any other way to improve execution time for this?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, coalesce, execution-time

I am running this query inside a stored procedure, but I want to improve performance since its taking hours to execute on 13.2 million rows affected. Is there any way to improve performance?

I am using Postgresql + PgAdmin.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO t_temporary_id_table ( 
    ref_date,
    id,
    client, 
    slcunda,
    count_single_1,         
    count_double_2,         
    count_e, 
    count_g, 
    count_m, 
    active, 
    valid_till_max, 
    id_2, 
    created ,
    lastmodified 
    )
with 
cte_tmp as (
    select 
        a.id,               
        mm.tenant,          
        c.slcunda,              
        d.single,           
        d.count_single,   
        e.double_1,         
        e.count_double_1,     
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_e",  
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_g",  
        SUM (CASE WHEN id_role = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "count_m",  
        case when min(status)='active' then 1 else 0 end active, 
        MAX(valid_till) as valid_till_max
        
    from schema1.struct a
    inner join 
    (
    select 
        id,
        max(valid_till) valid_till_max
    from 
        schema1.struct a
    group by 
        id
    ) b
    on 
    a.id=b.id and a.valid_till = b.valid_till_max
    left outer join 
    schema2.tenants mm on a.tsl_1_2 = mm.tenant 
    left outer join (
        select 
            id,
            key_1 as slcunda
        from    
            schema1.t_id 
        where 
            id in (Select id from schema1.t_id group by id having count(id)=1) 
    ) c
    on a.id=c.id
    left outer join(
        select 
        id,
        count_single,
        single 
        from (
            select
                id, 
                id_2 as single,
                id_2_role,
                count(id) over(partition by id) as count_single,
                row_number() over(partition by id order by id, id_2_role desc) as rn
            from 
                schema1.different_id_2
            where 
                id_2_role in ('03','08','17')   
            ) a
        where rn=1
    ) d
    on a.id=d.id
    left outer join(
        select 
        id,
        count_double_1,
        double_1
        from (
            select
                id, 
                id_2 as double_1,
                id_2_role,
                count(id) over(partition by id) as count_double_1,
                row_number() over(partition by id order by id, id_2_role desc) as rn 
            from 
                schema1.different_id_2
            where 
                id_2_role in ('06','19')    
        ) a
    where rn=1
    ) e 
    on a.id=e.id    
    group by a.id,mm.client,c.slcunda,d.single,d.count_single,e.double_1,e.count_double_1
),
y as ( 
    select * 
    from (
        SELECT 
            cte_tmp.id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            b.id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        inner join (
            select 
                id,
                id_2
            from (
                select 
                    id,
                    id_theory as id_2,
                    row_number() over(partition by id order by id) rn
                from
                    schema1.struct
            ) a 
        where rn=1  
        ) b
        on cte_tmp.id=b.id
        where
            count_e=1 and count_g=0 and count_m=0 and count_single=0 
        union all   
        SELECT 
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            single as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where 
            count_e=1 and count_g=0 and count_m=0 and count_single>=1
        union all
        SELECT
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            double_1 as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where
            count_e=0 and count_g=1 and count_m>=1 and active=1 and count_double>=1
        union all
        SELECT 
            id,
            client,
            slcunda,
            count_single as count_single_1, 
            count_double_1 as count_double_2, 
            count_e,
            count_g,
            count_m,
            active,
            valid_till_max,
            double_1 as id_2 
        FROM 
            cte_tmp
        where 
            count_e<>1 and count_g<>0 and count_m<>=0 and active=0 and count_double>=1
    ) a 
), 


z as (
    SELECT 
        cte_tmp.id,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single as count_single_1, 
        count_double_1 as count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max
    FROM cte_tmp
    except
    select 
        id,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max
    from y
),

temporary_result as (
    select 
        id::bigint,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max,
        '' as id_2
    from z
    union all
    select 
        id::bigint,
        client,
        slcunda,
        count_single_1,
        count_double_2,
        count_e,
        count_g,
        count_m,
        active,
        valid_till_max,
        id_2
    from y
)
select 
    now(),
    id,
    client,
    slcunda,
    count_single_1, 
    count_double_2, 
    count_e,
    count_g,
    count_m,
    active,
    valid_till_max,
    id_2::bigint,
    now(),
    now()
from temporary_result
```

```
QUERY PLAN
Insert on t_temporary_id_table  (cost=841905.48..842027.08 rows=206 width=48) (actual time=28853.074..28853.111 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=111871, local hit=1010060 read=2 dirtied=9372 written=18742, temp read=114117 written=92895
  I/O Timings: read=0.007
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=841905.48..842027.08 rows=206 width=48) (actual time=26620.987..28062.291 rows=991322 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
        ->  Result  (cost=841905.48..842019.35 rows=206 width=102) (actual time=26620.981..27612.767 rows=991322 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
              CTE cte_tmp
                ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=655151.28..655242.89 rows=1745 width=97) (actual time=20685.859..22471.231 rows=991322 loops=1)
                      Group Key: a.id, mm.tenant, t_id.key_1, a_1.single, a_1.count_single, a_2.double_1, a_2.count_double_1
                      Buffers: shared hit=91523, temp read=77862 written=77948
                      ->  Sort  (cost=655151.28..655155.64 rows=1745 width=78) (actual time=20685.833..21282.869 rows=999585 loops=1)
                            Sort Key: a.id, mm.tenant, t_id.key_1, a_1.single, a_1.count_single, a_2.double_1, a_2.count_double_1
                            Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 52920kB
                            Buffers: shared hit=91523, temp read=77862 written=77948
                            ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=605059.82..655057.32 rows=1745 width=78) (actual time=14404.197..19018.340 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                  Hash Cond: (a. tsl_1_2 = (mm.tenant)::numeric)
                                  Buffers: shared hit=91523, temp read=67869 written=67928
                                  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=605057.61..655028.93 rows=1745 width=79) (actual time=14404.146..18397.854 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                        Hash Cond: (a_2.id = a.id)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=91522, temp read=67869 written=67928
                                        ->  Subquery Scan on a_2  (cost=143319.32..193271.82 rows=4995 width=33) (actual time=1706.052..3753.365 rows=999246 loops=1)
                                              Filter: (a_2.rn = 1)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=7358, temp read=7362 written=7387
                                              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=143319.32..180783.69 rows=999050 width=46) (actual time=1706.049..3584.785 rows=999246 loops=1)
                                                    Buffers: shared hit=7358, temp read=7362 written=7387
                                                    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=143319.32..165797.94 rows=999050 width=38) (actual time=1706.034..2812.484 rows=999246 loops=1)
                                                          Buffers: shared hit=7358, temp read=7362 written=7387
                                                          ->  Sort  (cost=143319.32..145816.94 rows=999050 width=30) (actual time=1706.021..2170.216 rows=999246 loops=1)
                                                                Sort Key: different_id_2.id, different_id_2.id_2_role DESC
                                                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 40200kB
                                                                Buffers: shared hit=7358, temp read=7362 written=7387
                                                                ->  Seq Scan on different_id_2  (cost=0.00..19858.00 rows=999050 width=30) (actual time=0.029..419.960 rows=999246 loops=1)
                                                                      Filter: (id_2_role = ANY ('{6,19}'::numeric[]))
                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 754
                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                        ->  Hash  (cost=461716.48..461716.48 rows=1745 width=54) (actual time=12696.847..12696.862 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                              Buckets: 65536 (originally 2048)  Batches: 32 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3585kB
                                              Buffers: shared hit=84164, temp read=45823 written=51723
                                              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=407582.29..461716.48 rows=1745 width=54) (actual time=8198.967..12034.422 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                                    Hash Cond: (a.id = a_1.id)
                                                    Buffers: shared hit=84164, temp read=45823 written=45857
                                                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=386461.36..440588.99 rows=1745 width=29) (actual time=7848.284..11342.813 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                                          Hash Cond: (a.id = t_id.id)
                                                          Buffers: shared hit=76806, temp read=45823 written=45857
                                                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=194219.00..248340.00 rows=1745 width=26) (actual time=2108.327..4049.878 rows=999585 loops=1)
                                                                Hash Cond: ((a.id = struct.id) AND (a.valid_till = (max(struct.valid_till))))
                                                                Buffers: shared hit=40696, temp read=13666 written=13683
                                                                ->  Seq Scan on struct a  (cost=0.00..30348.00 rows=1000000 width=26) (actual time=0.016..323.130 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=20348
                                                                ->  Hash  (cost=174465.86..174465.86 rows=993476 width=12) (actual time=2107.791..2107.793 rows=991322 loops=1)
                                                                      Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 3929kB
                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=3902 written=7995
                                                                      ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=147096.34..164531.10 rows=993476 width=12) (actual time=884.285..1782.278 rows=991322 loops=1)
                                                                            Group Key: struct.id
                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=3902 written=3919
                                                                            ->  Sort  (cost=147096.34..149596.34 rows=1000000 width=12) (actual time=884.272..1368.369 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                                  Sort Key: struct.id
                                                                                  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 25496kB
                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=3902 written=3919
                                                                                  ->  Seq Scan on struct  (cost=0.00..30348.00 rows=1000000 width=12) (actual time=0.007..308.301 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=20348
                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=192179.85..192179.85 rows=5000 width=11) (actual time=5738.432..5738.436 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                Buckets: 131072 (originally 8192)  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3748kB
                                                                Buffers: shared hit=36110, temp read=22791 written=26489
                                                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=161499.84..192179.85 rows=5000 width=11) (actual time=1913.550..5318.612 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                      Hash Cond: (t_id.id = t_id_1.id)
                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=36110, temp read=22791 written=22808
                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on t_id (cost=0.00..28055.00 rows=1000000 width=11) (actual time=0.008..182.515 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=18055
                                                                      ->  Hash  (cost=161437.34..161437.34 rows=5000 width=8) (actual time=1913.370..1913.372 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                            Buckets: 131072 (originally 8192)  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3548kB
                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=18055, temp read=2861 written=6190
                                                                            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=141387.34..161387.34 rows=5000 width=8) (actual time=726.580..1619.438 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                                  Group Key: t_id_1.id
                                                                                  Filter: (count(t_id_1.id) = 1)
                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=18055, temp read=2861 written=2878
                                                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=141387.34..143887.34 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=726.568..1204.865 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                                        Sort Key: t_id_1.id
                                                                                        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 18704kB
                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=18055, temp read=2861 written=2878
                                                                                        ->  Seq Scan on t_id t_id_1  (cost=0.00..28055.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.004..156.615 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                                                              Buffers: shared hit=18055
                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=21120.92..21120.92 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=350.644..350.647 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
                                                          Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                                          ->  Subquery Scan on a_1  (cost=21113.42..21120.92 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=350.339..350.604 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                                Filter: (a_1.rn = 1)
                                                                Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                                                ->  WindowAgg  (cost=21113.42..21119.05 rows=150 width=46) (actual time=350.335..350.578 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                                      Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                                                      ->  WindowAgg  (cost=21113.42..21116.80 rows=150 width=38) (actual time=350.322..350.440 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                                            Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                                                            ->  Sort  (cost=21113.42..21113.80 rows=150 width=30) (actual time=350.302..350.318 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                                                  Sort Key: different_id_2_1.id, different_id_2_1.id_2_role DESC
                                                                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 36kB
                                                                                  Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                                                                  ->  Seq Scan on different_id_2 different_id_2_1  (cost=0.00..21108.00 rows=150 width=30) (actual time=0.987..350.004 rows=143 loops=1)
                                                                                        Filter: (id_2_role = ANY ('{03,08,17}'::numeric[]))
                                                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 999857
                                                                                        Buffers: shared hit=7358
                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1.54..1.54 rows=54 width=8) (actual time=0.037..0.038 rows=54 loops=1)
                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                        Buffers: shared hit=1
                                        ->  Seq Scan on tenants mm  (cost=0.00..1.54 rows=54 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.023 rows=54 loops=1)
                                              Buffers: shared hit=1
              CTE y
                ->  Append  (cost=153984.20..186662.59 rows=6 width=122) (actual time=1196.616..1645.006 rows=3588 loops=1)
                      Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=36255 written=6487
                      ->  Merge Join  (cost=153984.20..186496.72 rows=1 width=95) (actual time=1195.226..1195.229 rows=0 loops=1)
                            Merge Cond: (a_3.id = cte_tmp_1.id)
                            Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=10872 written=6487
                            ->  Subquery Scan on a_3  (cost=153931.84..186431.84 rows=5000 width=25) (actual time=1034.841..1034.842 rows=1 loops=1)
                                  Filter: (a_3.rn = 1)
                                  Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=2411 written=6486
                                  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=153931.84..173931.84 rows=1000000 width=33) (actual time=1034.839..1034.840 rows=1 loops=1)
                                        Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=2411 written=6486
                                        ->  Sort  (cost=153931.84..156431.84 rows=1000000 width=25) (actual time=1034.824..1034.826 rows=2 loops=1)
                                              Sort Key: struct_1.id
                                              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 35272kB
                                              Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=2411 written=6486
                                              ->  Seq Scan on struct struct_1  (cost=0.00..30348.00 rows=1000000 width=25) (actual time=0.019..229.951 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                                                    Buffers: shared hit=20348
                            ->  Sort  (cost=52.36..52.37 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=160.379..160.379 rows=0 loops=1)
                                  Sort Key: cte_tmp_1.id
                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                  Buffers: temp read=8461 written=1
                                  ->  CTE Scan on cte_tmp cte_tmp_1  (cost=0.00..52.35 rows=1 width=78) (actual time=160.369..160.369 rows=0 loops=1)
                                        Filter: ((count_e = 1) AND (count_g = 0) AND (count_m = 0) AND (count_single = 0))
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 991322
                                        Buffers: temp read=8461 written=1
                      ->  CTE Scan on cte_tmp cte_tmp_2  (cost=0.00..52.35 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=1.387..145.031 rows=5 loops=1)
                            Filter: ((count_single>= 1) AND (count_e = 1) AND (count_g = 0) AND (count_m = 0))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 991317
                            Buffers: temp read=8461
                      ->  CTE Scan on cte_tmp cte_tmp_3  (cost=0.00..56.71 rows=1 width=128) (actual time=0.054..151.483 rows=3579 loops=1)
                            Filter: ((count_m >= 1) AND (count_double >= 1) AND (count_e = 0) AND (count_g = 1) AND (active = 1))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 987743
                            Buffers: temp read=8461
                      ->  CTE Scan on cte_tmp cte_tmp_4  (cost=0.00..56.71 rows=3 width=128) (actual time=31.046..152.850 rows=4 loops=1)
                            Filter: ((count_e <> 1) AND (count_g <> 0) AND (count_m <> 0) AND (count_double >= 1) AND (active = 0))
                            Rows Removed by Filter: 991318
                            Buffers: temp read=8461
              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..108.73 rows=206 width=103) (actual time=26620.976..27439.782 rows=991322 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
                    ->  Subquery Scan on z  (cost=0.00..107.56 rows=200 width=102) (actual time=26620.975..27356.994 rows=987734 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
                          ->  HashSetOp Except  (cost=0.00..105.06 rows=200 width=82) (actual time=26620.971..27011.650 rows=987734 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
                                ->  Append  (cost=0.00..61.28 rows=1751 width=82) (actual time=20685.869..25367.475 rows=994910 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=111871, temp read=114117 written=92895
                                      ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..52.35 rows=1745 width=82) (actual time=20685.867..23595.424 rows=991322 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=91523, temp read=77862 written=86408
                                            ->  CTE Scan on cte_tmp  (cost=0.00..34.90 rows=1745 width=78) (actual time=20685.866..23423.809 rows=991322 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=91523, temp read=77862 written=86408
                                      ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..0.18 rows=6 width=82) (actual time=1196.623..1648.210 rows=3588 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=36255 written=6487
                                            ->  CTE Scan on y y_1  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=6 width=78) (actual time=1196.621..1647.533 rows=3588 loops=1)
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=20348, temp read=36255 written=6487
                    ->  CTE Scan on y  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=6 width=120) (actual time=0.004..1.137 rows=3588 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.647 ms
Execution Time: 28921.102 ms
```

Edit : Added the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS, FORMAT TEXT) result but how can I use this to improve performance?

Comment: Why do you use COALESCE() in the first place? You don't need it

Comment: Perhaps the constant is sometimes -1.

Comment: I have removed the cases where i get -1 so now ive removed coalesce from the query

Comment: The execution plan is unreadable. Connect with `psql`, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS` /* your query */` and copy and paste the result.

Comment: Tuning a complex statement like is really hard without access to the real system. But as some of the plan steps spill to disk, you might be able to scrape off some seconds by increasing `work_mem`, e.g. `set work_mem = '256MB';` - obviously this depends on how much memory your server has and how many concurrent queries are running

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your input , I will try it out. Do you have any suggestions for the indexes?

Answer (score 2):

```
AND count_d >= 1
```

`NULL` count_d will fail that test, just like `0` does, thus there is no need for the `COALESCE(count_d, 0)` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the execution plan, but given that you have the correct index, the `coalesce` need not be a problem.

Assuming that all these conditions are selective, that is, they narrow the result set considerably, the ideal index would be

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_a (count_e, count_f, count_g, coalesce(count_d, 0));
```

If one of the conditions is not selective, omit it from the index.

Comment: I have added the execution plan

Comment: It is unreadable. The function you quote in your question doesn't seem to contain `coalesce`.

Comment: I have removed coalesce since the cases with -1 have been removed from the data.
`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS ` with my query is taking too long 2+ hours. However EXPLAIN alone works fine, would it be useful? I can add it to the question. @Laurenz

Comment: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` alone is enough - but it has to be readable.

Comment: I have added the result of EXPLAIN, is it readable ? @Laurenz Albe

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. Unfortunately your query is too long for me to analyze. Perhaps somebody else will feel motivated.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping me put the execution plan there in the question. @LaurenzAlbe Can you comment on the indexes only maybe? im using the following indexes  
For table struct : id, valid_till, tsl_1_2  

For table t_id : id  

For table different_id_2 : id_2_role, id

Comment: Also could you help me with some links from which I can learn to analyze query plans for performance? thankyou @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original question which was about a single table.  The question has been drastically altered since then.

`coalesce()` is superfluous, because `NULL` will fail the condition, so:

```
where count_e = 1 and count_f = 0 and count_g = 0 and count_d >= 1
```

However, it is really doubtful that removing the `coalesce()` would affect performance.

What would change performance is writing the query like this and then adding an index on `(count_e, count_f, count_g, count_d)`.  The order of the first three columns in the index is not important, but `count_d` should follow those columns, because of the inequality.

Comment: I have added the indexes and the complete query still takes over an hour to complete
The total no. of rows affected is 13 million plus

Comment: @SaadMustafa . . . Your execution plan suggests that the query is much more complicated than what you have shown.

Comment: I will add the complete query so its more understandable @Gordon Linoff

Comment: I have added the complete query @Gordon Linoff

Comment: You are getting there. Use `FORMAT TEXT` instead of `FORMAT JSON` and add the `ANALYZE` and `BUFFER` options.

Comment: I think this is what you were asking for (hopefully) @LaurenzAlbe
please note that I used a subset (1 M rows) of the original dataset for the `EXPLAIN (Analyze, buffers) ` since it was taking too long for the original dataset